# count of controls used in each page of an ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to find out the count of controls used in each page of an ASP.Net application?
Please help

Comment: Why do you need it? Define controls first, everything that derives from `System.Web.UI.Control`?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need it? Define controls first, everything that derives from `System.Web.UI.Control`?

You could write a recursive extension method which which returns all controls lazily, then it is simple:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var allControls = this.GetControlsRecursively().ToList();
}
```

Here a possible implementation:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsRecursively(this Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return c;

            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control control in c.GetControlsRecursively())
                {
                    yield return control;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor point: instead of `c.Controls.Count > 0`, use [`c.HasControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.hascontrols.aspx) - should be slightly faster

Comment: @HansKesting: Thanks, edited it accordingly. But i assume that performance is not the reason why we should prefer `HasControls`. Touching the `Controls` property recursively will cause the ViewState to be loaded if not already done for all controls, that can cause side effects. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5278825/284240